# Login to a jsp login page using python requests

Tags: javascript, python, jsp, authentication

I have a broadband connection that require me to login whenever i want to use internet.

But for some reason they have a bug that log me out without any warning randomly so i want to make a python script that logs me in whenever i get logged out (i can make a cronjob with the script)

because it is a login server it is not visit-able from the internet

so i have provided the login form of the page, that should be enough right for making a post request ?

***if not let me know i will provide the source code***

**here is the form of the login page of my broadband provider**

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="loginUI.do2" onsubmit="if (this.checker.checked) toMem(this)" id="login-form">






<div id="templatemo_wrapper">
    <div id="templatemo_menu">
<marquee scrollamount="3" behavior="slide" direction="left" height="20" width="100%" style="color:#00162b"><p>&nbsp; Your Default Password is <strong style="color:#FFFFFF">wnpl123</strong> for first time login only. Please change your password after first login.</p></marquee>
    </div> <!-- end of templatemo_menu -->

    <div id="templatemo_header_bar">

    <div id="headerrs">
       <img src="images/pay.png" width="650">  </div>

<div id="header"><!--<div class="right"></div>-->

                <h1><a href="#">
                    <img src="images/templatemo_logo.png" alt="Site Title" width="254">
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                </a></h1>
      </div>

            <div style=" font-size:22px; color:#000; margin-top:10px; float:right; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; left: 878px; top: 0px; width: 285px;"> Toll Free : 1800 419 4244</div>

    </div> <!-- end of templatemo_header_bar -->

    <div class="cleaner"></div>

    <div id="sidebar"><div class="sidebar_top"></div><div class="sidebar_bottom"></div>

        <div class="sidebar_section">

            <h2>Login Form</h2>
            <div style="color:#FFFF00; font-size:12px; margin-top:45px; margin-bottom:10px;"><b>

        </b></div>


                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="Username" size="20" class="input_field">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" value="" name="Password" class="input_field" title="password">
                <input type="hidden" name="LoginName">
                <input type="hidden" name="LoginPassword">
               <label for="checkbox"><br><input type="checkbox" name="checker" id="checker"> Remember Me</label>
            <br>


 <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submit_btn" onclick="return validateForm()">



        </div>
```

*this is the link before login*

http://192.168.183.201:9088/WISHN/Login.jsp

*this is the link after login*

http://192.168.183.201:9088/WISHN/Home.jsp

**i tried this with cookiejar it doesn't work**

```
import requests
import cookielib


jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
login_url = 'http://192.168.183.201:9088/WISHN/Login.jsp'
acc_pwd = {'Username':'my username',
           'Password':'my password'
          }
r = requests.get(login_url, cookies=jar)
r = requests.post(login_url, cookies=jar, data=acc_pwd)


page = requests.get('http://192.168.183.201:9088/WISHN/loginUI.do2', cookies=jar)

print page.text
```

**i have tried only with requests**

```
import requests

url = 'http://192.168.183.201:9088/WISHN/loginUI.do2'
payload = {
    'Username': 'my username',
    'Password': 'my password',}

s = requests.Session()
response = s.post(url, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

***but as expected this does not work***

and as you can see the action and the method is post

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="loginUI.do2" onsubmit="if (this.checker.checked) toMem(this)" id="login-form">
```

I do not want to use selenium webdriver i want to make this lightweight

EDIT:
the screenshot when i used the firefox tamper data addon when making the post request

[image]

Comment: why is this tagged php?

Comment: removed sorry it was in the tag recommendation so i clicked

Answer (score 1):

Try this with updated payload, use "Tamper Data" add-on in firefox to inspect the requests and update the payload accordingly.

```
import requests

url = 'http://192.168.183.201:9088/WISHN/loginUI.do2'
payload = {
    "Username" : "Your Username"
    "Password" : "Your Password"
    "LoginName" : ""
    "LoginPassword" : ""
    "checker" : ""
    }
s = requests.Session()
response = s.post(url, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: LoginName, LoginPassword and checker contain no value do i keep them blank ?

Comment: response.text shows the same page before login and for some reason the post is not working

Comment: Use tamper data addon to see if it is sending some extra parameters.

Comment: i have used tamper data addon and edited the question to added the tamper data screenshot

Comment: the part that is scribbled is my username and password

Comment: the LoginName and LoginPassword is not blank here they are generating some value

Comment: what are those values, is it constant for all logins? try checking the page source for how its generating those values.

Comment: no it is not static for all logins they are changing for each session

Comment: can you paste the login name values here, since they are different?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147002/discussion-between-stack-and-shantanu-bedajna).